# Email not being sent using smtp.js

Tags: javascript, email, smtp, gmail

I have some javascript which i am using to send some email from my app.
I referenced both smtp.js and my javascript in my html code.
When I send the email the alert tells me the email has been sent.  Recently google will not allow 'less secure app' function so i am now using 2 step verification and app password for my settings.  regardless ... the email does not get delivered.  Can anyone tell me why?

```
const btn = document.getElementById("2")
const inputs = document.getElementById("1")

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    Email.send({
        Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        Username: "mygmail@gmail.com",
        Password: "my app password",
        To: "target@gmail.com",
        From: inputs.elements["email"].value,
        Subject: "Contact Us Query by the Customer",
        Body: "Test"
    }).then(msg => alert("Email Sent"))
})
```